# Which function grows faster?

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics

Which function grows faster

$()= 2^{^2+3}$ and $() = 2^{+1}$

by using the limit theorem I will first simplify

then I will just get $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2^{n^2+3n}}{2^{n+1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{n^2+3n-n-1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{n^2+2n-1}=\infty$$

Is this enough? 
I say it will go then to infinity so the $f(n)$ is growing faster? I am asking this question because I have to find it by using limit but I didn't need to use l'hopital rule!

Comment: I reformatted your limits, but I didn't change the arithmetic (or at least, I didn't intend to).  You appear to have mishandled the exponents.

Comment: @lulu could you see the question again I edit the 1 , must be on the power of 2

Comment: Yes.  With that edit , your arithmetic is correct.  And your argument is sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Before Edit:**
Your idea was correct, but you didn’t simplify the limit properly.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n^2+3n}}{2^n+1}$$
It is enough to divide both the numerator and denominator by $2^n$.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{2^{n^2+3n}}{2^n}}{\frac{2^n+1}{2^n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n^2+3n-n}}{2^{n-n}+\frac{1}{2^n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n^2+2n}}{1+\frac{1}{2^n}}$$
As $n \to \infty$, it becomes clear that the limit tends to $\infty$ since the numerator tends to $\infty$ while the denominator tends to $1$.

**After Edit:** Yes, your way is correct.

Comment: I forget to add brackets on the second function, it must be $2^{n+1}$ @KM101

Comment: Well, I guess all the answers are pointless now. :-)

Comment: sorry for that! and thanks, then shall I put the first question too so that it wouldn't be pointless !! :) @KM101

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

You conclusion is correct but that step is wrong

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}= \dfrac{2^{n^2+3n}}{2^n+1}\color{red}{=\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{n^2+3n-n-1}}$$

you could use that $2^n+1\le 2^{n+1}$ and therefore

$$\dfrac{2^{n^2+3n}}{2^n+1}\ge \dfrac{2^{n^2+3n}}{2^{n+1}}$$

**Update after editing**

For $g(n)=2^{n+1}$ your method is absolutely correct.

What about $f(n)=2^{n^2+3n}$ and $g(n)=3^{n+1}$?

Comment: I have this question too! but couldn't find any idea how to start solving it, because of the 3 ! any hint ?? @gimusi

Comment: @NANA We could use $3^{n+1}\le 4^{n+1}$.

Comment: $3^{n+1}=2^{(log_23)(n+1)}$

Answer (score 2):

It is $$\frac{2^{n^2}\cdot 2^{3n}}{2^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)}=\frac{2^{n^2+2n}}{1+\frac{1}{2^n}}$$